# how to formaStyle a row by index /rowname with datatable in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, datatable

I'm doing a Shiny app and I have troubles to put some style and color.

I'm trying to put some color on my datatable : I want to color a specific row.
the rowname of this row is "Sum".

I also wanted to color the column "Sum" and I succeed to do it :
So I can color a specific column named "Sum" like this :

```
output$data_1<-renderDataTable(datatable(data(),options = list(dom = 't',pageLength=100))%>%formatStyle("Sum", backgroundColor = "orange")
```

But I don't know how i can do the same type of thing with my row ?

edit : my "Sum" row is not always the last row in my data.

Thank you for your help ! :)

EDIT :

A simple example :

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

data_example<-data.frame("A"=c(40,10,20,10,5,85),"B"=c(10,20,10,20,5,65),"Sum"=c(50,30,30,30,10,150), row.names = c("1","2","3", "4", "5", "Sum"))

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Example"),
    dataTableOutput("table")

)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$table <- renderDataTable(datatable(data_example)%>%formatStyle("Sum", backgroundColor = "orange"))
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

EDIT :

Thanks to akrun , i finally find a way a generalisable expression to do it with all my table :

```
output$table <- renderDataTable(datatable(data_example)%>%formatStyle("Sum", backgroundColor = "orange")
                                    %>%formatStyle(0, target="row",backgroundColor =  styleEqual("Sum", "orange"))
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: I add a simple example ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may specify the index for rows as `0` in `formatStyle`, and use `styleEqual` to match and replace the 'cols1' created

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  v1 <- row.names(data_example)
  cols1 <- ifelse(v1 =='Sum','orange','')
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable(datatable(data_example)%>%
        formatStyle(0, target = "row",
                            backgroundColor = styleEqual(v1, cols1)))
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: oooh Thanks ! 
I finally do it like that :

output$table <- renderDataTable(datatable(data_example)%>%formatStyle("Sum", backgroundColor = "orange")
                                    %>%formatStyle(0, target="row",backgroundColor =  styleEqual("Sum", "orange"))

Answer (score 1):

My solution according to @akrun answer ! ^^

```
  output$table <- renderDataTable(datatable(data_example)%>%formatStyle("Sum", backgroundColor = "orange")
                                        %>%formatStyle(0, target="row",backgroundColor =  styleEqual("Sum", "orange"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution how highlight by bold font some rows in data frame (mtcars as an example)

```
library(DT)

# SERVER side
df_mtcars <- reactive({
  mtcars$show <- (mtcars$mpg > 20)
})

# UI side
output$dt_mtcars <- renderDataTable(
  df_mtcars() %>% 
    datatable(
      rownames = FALSE,
      options = list(
        columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, targets = c('show'))))) %>% 
    formatStyle(
      'show', target = 'row',
      fontWeight = styleEqual(c(1), c('bold'))))
```